# Cross-compile gcc on OS X failed: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross-compile i386-elf-gcc on OS X 10.9 using

```
./configure --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,go,java,objc,obj-c++ \
            --enable-stage1-languages=c++ \
            --prefix=/usr/local/i386-efi-gcc --target=i386-elf
```

and

```
make -j 16
```

Finally I got such an error:

```
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/src/gcc-4.9.1/i386-elf/libgcc':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.
Makefile:10818: recipe for target 'configure-target-libgcc' failed
make[1]: *** [configure-target-libgcc] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/src/gcc-4.9.1'
Makefile:874: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I checked out `/src/gcc-4.9.1/i386-elf/libgcc/config.log`:

```
configure:3580: checking for suffix of object files
configure:3602: /src/gcc-4.9.1/host-x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0/gcc/xgcc -B/src/gcc-4.9.1/host-x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0/gcc/ -B/usr/local/i386-efi-gcc/i386-elf/bin/ -B/usr/local/i386-efi-gcc/i386-elf/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/i386-efi-gcc/i386-elf/include -isystem /usr/local/i386-efi-gcc/i386-elf/sys-include    -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
/src/gcc-4.9.1/host-x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0/gcc/as: line 106: exec: -o: invalid option
exec: usage: exec [-cl] [-a name] file [redirection ...]
configure:3606: $? = 1
```

I realize there may be something wrong with `/src/gcc-4.9.1/host-x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0/gcc/as`. Below is what I see in the beginning of it:

```
# Invoke as, ld or nm from the build tree.

ORIGINAL_AS_FOR_TARGET=""
ORIGINAL_LD_FOR_TARGET=""
ORIGINAL_LD_BFD_FOR_TARGET="/.bfd"
ORIGINAL_LD_GOLD_FOR_TARGET="/.gold"
ORIGINAL_PLUGIN_LD_FOR_TARGET=""
ORIGINAL_NM_FOR_TARGET=""
```

Apparently, `ORIGINAL_AS_FOR_TARGET` shouldn't be empty. Since the `as` script is generated by `gcc-4.9.1/gcc/configure`, I checked out `gcc-4.9.1/host-x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0/gcc/config.log` and found out:

```
configure:21319: checking for i386-elf-as
configure:21352: result: no
configure:21368: checking what assembler to use
configure:21409: result: 
configure:21483: checking for i386-elf-ld
configure:21516: result: no
configure:21549: checking whether we are using gold
configure:21558: result: no
configure:21569: checking what linker to use
configure:21603: result: 
configure:21631: checking for i386-elf-nm
configure:21664: result: no
configure:21672: checking what nm to use
configure:21680: result: 
configure:21711: checking for i386-elf-objdump
configure:21744: result: no
configure:21752: checking what objdump to use
configure:21759: result: not found
configure:21781: checking for readelf
configure:21799: found /usr/local/bin/readelf
configure:21811: result: /usr/local/bin/readelf
configure:21822: checking what readelf to use
configure:21832: result: /usr/local/bin/readelf
```

I think maybe things were going wrong here.

Why the error occurs and how can I successfully cross-compile gcc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A major prerequisite for compiling gcc is to have compiled a corresponding binutils package for the same target first. You can get the latest binutils here:

http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/

Frist compile and install the binutils package using the same target prefix (and make sure it will provide you with i386-elf-as, i386-elf-ld, etc.). Then start from a clean slate with your gcc build (= remove the directory where your build failed and extract the files again). Just make sure your binutils binaries are in PATH when you run your ./configure.

Hopefully that will get you forward.